# How to construct a Django model that is purely made from other models related by ticker?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to make up a "parent" model that is solely composed of other models ?  I am currently thinking to use foreignkey relationships but I don't believe this is the right way to do so.

```
class BalanceSheet(models.Model):
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(
        Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="balance_sheets"
    )

    assets = models.ForeignKey(Assets, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liab_and_stockholders_equity = models.ForeignKey(LiabAndStockholdersEquity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.ticker} Balance Sheet"

class Assets(model.Model):
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(
    Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="assets")
    balance_sheet = ????????????????????????????



class Assets(model.Model):
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(
    Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="liab_and_stockholders_equity")
    balance_sheet = ??????????????????????????
```

Comment: As much as I know, whenever one table is solely composed of other tables', a foreign key is actually the right way to connect them. Your parent table will have `ForeignKey()` to the child ones

Comment: so you believe this is correct ?

Comment: I believe so because I've seen ER diagrams with this scheme, thus this is the way I'd do myself. However, there might be better options I'm unaware of.

Comment: and for example, when the `BalanceSheet` model has a `ForeignKey` of `ticker` on it should I put that same foreign key on all the other "child" models as well ?

Comment: No, I think what you need to do is create a model for the parent table, and there you will have `child1 =  ForeignKey(Child1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`, `child2 =  ForeignKey(Child2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` and so on for each child you want to have connection to. No need to write this in child models, only in parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is create a model for the parent table, and there you will have `child1 =  ForeignKey(Child1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
`child2 =  ForeignKey(Child2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` and so on for each child, you want to have a connection to. No need to write this in child models, only in the parent.